# Windows 10 slow running performance when joined an AD and using an AD-Account

Tags: windows-10, performance, windows-domain

We recently updated our teams infrastructure to Windows 10 within an AD.

Everything works fine except:
We're observing slow performance in some situations. First observed was it as our Post-Compiling Powershell skript within VS2017 ran slower than below Windows 7. Google was also not helpful - but by now we hadn't the time to investigate further. Now recently we updated our CI build farm, too (TeamCity as CI Server). There we saw increasing build times by over 100% - a build for reference took 7m33s before the upgrade, after it stays at 17m05s.

Research here at StackExchange and google were not expressive.
A little more research brought us the finding that if we run the Agent with an local account on the machine (still in AD) we're getting build times around 8m50s.

The buildjob contains different MSBuild steps, nUnint runner and some powershell steps. No network activity - all is done locally on the agent. One MSBuild step took previously 36s and now 1m02s. Same with the NUint step - 30s vs 1m24s (all with the AD-User).

Any suggestion where the problem is?

Comment: Does the domain have any special GPOs (gpresult /r), and/or does it install any data loss prevention software? Do you observe any network traffic during the build? Maybe the domain account uses "folder redirection" so that all your data is kept on a fileserver?

Comment: Nothing special here - only a few gpos:

Angewendete Gruppenrichtlinienobjekte
    --------------------------------------
        GPO-Passwords
        GPO_WSUS-Agents
        GPO_AutomaticLogin
        GPO_DisableUAC
        GPO-DisableTelemetry
        GPO-DisableCortana
        GPO-LocalAdmins
        GPO-Printer
        GPO-OpenFirewallForRPC
        GPO-PowershellExecutionPolicy
        GPO_WSUS
        Default Domain Policy
No Software is distributed on our automated agents nor are the user profiles are on a central server (everything runs local).

Comment: Also nothing special at network traffic (or i didn't discovered it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution. It was a combination of Windows 10, MSBuild and our company infrastructure.

TeamCity wraps the MSBuild call. This wrapper, or some windows component inside, tries to communicate with "akamaitechnologies" - a CDN know Microsoft uses it for telemetry. As our company network is behind a proxy the request need to timeout. At the domain user this timeout was surprisingly longer than on the local accounts. The solution (why at also worked on the old local account) was to activate the system Proxy. Know the request gets immediately a "denied" response from the proxy. Build times went down to normal times.

Thanks to anyone who tried to help me out at this problem!